# Tiering after clustering with Kmeans

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, indexing

I would like to have some suggestions on possible avenues that would make sense in the following context.

- 3 Optimal clusters have been identified in a 5000 list of customers
  using Kmeans
- Data model has 30 features and a PCA was performed prior to Kmeans.

I would like to further breakdown each of these 3 clusters into smaller tiers for each cluster. These tiers would server in ranking each customer within his cluster.

For example: Cluster 1, 2, 3 could all have 4 or 5 tiers.

**What interesting option could I explore to create the tiers within the 3 clusters (e.g. RFM quantile separation, classification algorithms)?**

Comment: why not kmeans again?

Comment: maybe hierarchical clustering can cluster and subcluster automatically

Comment: @NikosM. i've tried kmeans but it isnt performing in a desirable way. hierarchical could be interesting

Answer (score 0):

One option is [hierarchical clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) which builds a hierarchy of clusters.